# In Pandas how can I increment values correctly for each row and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

assuming I have this table:

```
data = {'column1': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1'],
        'column2': ['A2', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
        'column3': ['A1', 'A3', 'A3', 'A3'],
        'column4': ['A4', 'A4', 'A1', 'A4'],
        'column5': ['A5', 'A5', 'A5', 'A5']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

which looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| A1      | A2      | A1      | A4      | A5      |
| A1      | A1      | A3      | A4      | A5      |
| A1      | A2      | A3      | A1      | A5      |
| A1      | A6      | A3      | A4      | A5      |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Is there a way to correctly increment the number on each value in column per row? By Moving from left to right per row. If the value is not "A1", we should increment correctly.

The output should be like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| A1      | A2      | A1      | A3      | A4      |
| A1      | A1      | A2      | A3      | A4      |
| A1      | A2      | A3      | A1      | A4      |
| A1      | A2      | A3      | A4      | A5      |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I could loop with each row, but the problem is I might be dealing with large number of rows.

Comment: You seem to be decrementing, not incrementing. But I don't understand why you're not decrementing everyhting. Why does column4 A4 go to A3 in the first 2 rows, but not the last row?

Comment: And in column 2 you only decrement the last row. What's the logic?

Comment: its moving per row per column (sideways). going left to right. But all "A1" is ignored.

Comment: I still don't see it. In the first row, A2 doesn't move sideways. Where did A3 come from?

Comment: post the correct output, it doesn't fit the described conditions.

Comment: @Barmar order is not important as the rows might have different values, we are kind of resetting the index. Updated the example on the last row (A6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, use a [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) on the non-A1 values, and put the A1 back with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
m = df.ne('A1')

out = (m
  .cumsum(axis=1).add(1).astype(str).radd('A')
  .where(m, 'A1')
)
```

Output:

```
  colmn1 column2 column3 column4 column5
0     A1      A2      A1      A3      A4
1     A1      A1      A2      A3      A4
2     A1      A2      A3      A1      A4
3     A1      A2      A3      A4      A5
```

Comment: ahh mask and then cumsum. Very interesting. Thank you very much.